# how can I have commas instead of space in a given set of number

Tags: python, list

I have a set of number say

```
s = "39401.99865    7292.4753   8541.03675  6098.54185  106352.218  7300.4485   5699.983    5538.44755  5934.8514   7477.62475  5956.7409   9170.98 9481.5082   6063.4508   9380.92255"
```

I want to create a list of this number like

```
my_list = [ 39401.99865, 7292.4753  8541.03675, 6098.54185 , 106352.218 ,   7300.4485 ,5699.983 ,5538.44755 5934.8514, 7477.62475,  5956.7409,  9170.98,    9481.5082,  6063.4508   9380.92255]
```

How can i achieve this? I tried using regular expression but it converted my data into string.

```
s = '98 9 19'
s = re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)', ',', s)

print s
```

Comment: try using `map(float, s.split())`

Comment: That first line *is a string*. The second line is not a string literal, but it's Python syntax for an array.

Comment: Thanks @JulienBernu resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> s = "39401.99865    7292.4753   8541.03675  6098.54185  106352.218  7300.4485   5699.983    5538.44755  5934.8514   7477.62475  5956.7409   9170.98 9481.5082   6063.4508   9380.92255" 
>>> [float(item) for item in s.split()]
[39401.99865, 7292.4753, 8541.03675, 6098.54185, 106352.218, 7300.4485, 5699.983, 5538.44755, 5934.8514, 7477.62475, 5956.7409, 9170.98, 9481.5082, 6063.4508, 9380.92255]
```

Or you can use `map`

```
>>> map(float, s.split())
[39401.99865, 7292.4753, 8541.03675, 6098.54185, 106352.218, 7300.4485, 5699.983, 5538.44755, 5934.8514, 7477.62475, 5956.7409, 9170.98, 9481.5082, 6063.4508, 9380.92255]
```